# .htaccess 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I followed a pretty simple tutorial yet get `500` when i try. (of course, testfolder & user_name is in place of real credentials). the dir in question is owned by root. the user i used on the last line of .htaccess is only declared in their and when i create the htpasswd. its not a system user

**.htaccess**

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/testfolder/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /www.null
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic

require user USER_NAME
```

**apache2.conf (append)**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/testfolder">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

Comment: Require should be capitalized, but I don't think that's causing your error.  Why do you have the `AuthGroupFile ` defined like that? Try and comment it out, then restart apache.

Comment: Check your error logs, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just test, and the problem is coming from the line **AuthGroupFile /www.null**

Comment: thanks, it that line was from the tutorial i followed. will accept answer as soon as i can

Comment: @Simon. This is why you shouldn't follow tutorials without understanding them.